# Can't put variable begin with '@' in comments

Tags: support, comments

We can define a variable begin with '@' symbol in many languages. I have tried to put a comments for the below question by specifying two '@' variables but I can't. In the nature of the comments section is allowing '@' following some string to specify the person to whom to send the message. If we are specifying more '@' then, it'll not allowing to enter it.

An example: 
[Ruby Array Intersection Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23729520/ruby-array-intersection-issue)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add those comments if you place your variables in `backticks`, like this:

> [image: a comment saying: this is a <code>@test</code> <code>@test2</code>]

which becomes...

> [image: both appear just fine]

This appears in our [comment formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), which that 'help' link below the <kbd>Add Comment</kbd> button will summarise for you. This is for code markup, which makes it totally appropriate here for mentioning your variables. Try to reserve using it for code markup though.